# How to turn a 'term' in a QuantumError into a QuantumError?

Tags: programming, qiskit, noise

A [QuantumError class](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.QuantumError.html) may have many terms, and we can use `.error_term(position)` to have a look at each term. But it returns a list instead of another QuantumError class. What should I do if I want to find out how this single term works in the noise model?

Comment: Hello, could you maybe show an example of what you are talking about or be more specific? Like a little code of what you are working with, what you are able to get, and what information you would want to retrieve from that? This will help you get more reactions for your question :)